# Why is my wnck.screen_get_default() call hanging or crashing when launched through upstart?

Tags: python, ubuntu, upstart, wnck

When I run the following script manually, everything works fine. However, when I launch it on-boot through Upstart via a shell script (which launches the script as root) it successfully gets to the `wnck.screen_get_default()` line and never goes beyond it. Upstart keeps respawning the script over and over (since it keeps dying) and no exceptions are thrown. Any ideas?

```
import gtk
import wnck
import time

def cycle():
    try:
        print("ABOUT TO RUN screen_get_default!!")
        screen = wnck.screen_get_default()
        print("JUST RAN screen_get_default!!")
    except Exception as e:
        print(str(e))

print("STARTING APP!!")

while 1 == 1:
    cycle()
    time.sleep(1)
```

The upstart script looks like the following:

```
description "myapp"
start on runlevel [12345]
stop on runlevel [!12345]
respawn
exec /usr/lib/myapp/myapp.sh
post-stop exec sleep 10
```

EDIT: I ran `exec sudo python /usr/lib/myapp/myapp.py` from the upstart script and now I am finally getting a meaningful error in the log file, but I can't decipher where to go from here:

```
GtkWarning: IA__gdk_x11_display_get_xdisplay: assertion 'GDK_IS_DISPLAY (display)' failed
  screen = wnck.screen_get_default()
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0/gtk/__init__.py:57: GtkWarning: could not open display
  warnings.warn(str(e), _gtk.Warning)
```

Comment: What does the upstart script look like?

Comment: I added the upstart script to the question above.

Comment: If the python code included above is meant to be run by `exec /usr/lib/myapp/myapp.sh` try instead `python /usr/lib/myapp/myapp.py`

Comment: That fails as well. Not sure why... because it doesn't log anything at all when I do that. myapp.py ultimately needs to run with sudo privileges so the upstart script calls an sh script that, as root, calls sudo python myapp.py. I tried running the python script not as root, and that made no difference either.

Comment: What the error is saying is that there is no screen/display/gdk/x11/window. One place to look is how it is positioned in upstart, if it is looking for something that hasn't started yet, then it will not find it. Perhaps have that be the very last thing to run in upstart One possible solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27646435/gtkwarning-could-not-open-display