# Segmentation fault: 11 - python unexpectedly quits

Tags: python, gtk

I'm trying to run a program I downloaded and after installing everything I was instructed to, this is what terminal gives me, before python unexpectedly quits:

```
** (process:18933): WARNING **: Trying to register gtype 'GMountMountFlags' as enum when in fact it is of type 'GFlags'

** (process:18933): WARNING **: Trying to register gtype 'GDriveStartFlags' as enum when in fact it is of type 'GFlags'

** (process:18933): WARNING **: Trying to register gtype 'GSocketMsgFlags' as enum when in fact it is of type 'GFlags'
/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gtk-2.0/gtk/__init__.py:57: GtkWarning: could not open display
  warnings.warn(str(e), _gtk.Warning)
start.py:29: Warning: invalid (NULL) pointer instance
start.py:29: Warning: g_signal_connect_data: assertion 'G_TYPE_CHECK_INSTANCE (instance)' failed
start.py:29: GtkWarning: gtk_settings_get_for_screen: assertion 'GDK_IS_SCREEN (screen)' failed
start.py:29: Warning: g_object_get: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
start.py:29: GtkWarning: gdk_screen_get_display: assertion 'GDK_IS_SCREEN (screen)' failed
start.py:29: Warning: g_object_ref: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
start.py:29: GtkWarning: gdk_pango_context_get_for_screen: assertion 'GDK_IS_SCREEN (screen)' failed
start.py:29: PangoWarning: pango_context_set_font_description: assertion 'context != NULL' failed
start.py:29: PangoWarning: pango_context_set_base_dir: assertion 'context != NULL' failed
start.py:29: PangoWarning: pango_context_set_language: assertion 'context != NULL' failed
start.py:29: Warning: g_object_unref: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
start.py:29: GtkWarning: gdk_keymap_get_for_display: assertion 'GDK_IS_DISPLAY (display)' failed
Segmentation fault: 11
```

What did I do wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of [GtkWarning: could not open display](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27646435/gtkwarning-could-not-open-display)

Comment: The segfault is probably a bug in your program, whatever it is, where it is not properly handling GTK failing to open the display (or possibly the bug is in pygtk itself as suggested in the other question).

Comment: That link seems to be talking about a server connection, but I'm not connecting to a server.

Comment: You are connecting to an X server if your program tries to use a GUI :)  I'm guessing this is on Linux?  Or is it OSX?

Comment: I'm using Mac OS 10.9. I obviously don't know what I'm doing here.

Comment: Your program (it might help to know what it is) uses a windowing library called GTK to draw its GUI.  My understanding (I don't use OSX so I'm not sure) is that GTK still does not really support the native Mac graphics interface (called Quartz) and instead still needs an xserver to work, so you need to have [XQuartz](http://xquartz.macosforge.org/landing/) installed, which is an X server that runs on top of Quartz.  I know some of my coworkers use this to run various X11-only applications on their Macs.

Comment: BTW, if you're trying to set up a Python environment for scientific computing you might have better luck using one of the scientific Python distributions like Anaconda or Canopy (I am not affiliated with either).  I don't know if they include PyGTK as well, but you'll probably have fewer headaches overall :)  (and you'll still need XQuartz to run a GTK app on your Mac)

Comment: The program is [foci counter](http://focicounter.sourceforge.net/installation.html).

Comment: Any luck with XQuartz?  That would most likely be the way to go.

Comment: GTK does support the native Mac interface but if you're running the program yourself it's difficult to get set up yourself. I wouldn't recommend that, since Foci Counter isn't packaged for Mac. I would suggest your best bet for getting this running is [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/) - try `brew install pygtk`.

Comment: XQuartz worked! Thank you!